# Managing workspace and open programs with a bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, workspaces

I am trying to setup my laptop with a script that aims to create multiple workspaces and open some programs. I am new to bash and this is my script

```
 #!/bin/bash         

xdotool set_num_desktops 5 &

xdotool set_desktop 0 & 
nohup opera --new-window https://duo.dur.ac.uk > /dev/null

xdotool set_desktop 1 &
nohup opera --new-window http://tomato.es > /dev/null

xdotool set_desktop 2 &
nohup spotify > /dev/null

xdotool set_desktop 3 &
nohup opera --new-window > /dev/null
```

However this is not working, the script create 5 workspaces as required, however it stops after creating the first window of Opera. To create the other windows, I have to close to first one.

Answer (score 0):

the script says to wait until opera ends (ie. exits) before continuing to the next window of opera ... so it's doing what is scripted.

The `&` on many of your lines tell it to do the command in the background (ie. don't wait), which isn't on the opera, spotify lines which means the script pauses until those lines finish.

Comment: I have tried to add the `&` on the other lines as well, but the script doesn't work in that case.

Comment: at the end of the command and before the redirection?  (or did you have the `&` as part of the redirection?)

Comment: Ok so I added `&` on the end of every line (apart from the last). However, now sometimes the script opens all windows in the same desktop and other times it just doesn't do anything (it try to open some windows, but they very quickly close).

Comment: I haven't used `xdotool` so I don't want to comment on it. when I've done something similar, I've usually used `wmctl` which I'm aware doesn't work with every DE or WM.  I'm guessing you may need to add a pause (sleep or equiv.) to force the script to delay until your workstation has completed the required gui.app.load task, but this will be hardware|machine specific (longer for slower hardware..)

Comment: Ok I'll try with `wmctrl`